# What's the pythonic way to set class variables?

Tags: python

perhaps I'm asking the wrong question.  I have code like this:

```
class ExpressionGrammar(Grammar):
  def __init__(self, nonterminals, terminals, macros, rules, precedence, nonterminal_name = '_expr'):
    self.nonterminals = nonterminals
    self.terminals = terminals
    self.rules = rules
    self.macros = macros
    self.precedence = precedence
    self.nonterminal = nonterminal
```

and I find it redundant to always have to to self.x = x.  I know python tries to avoid repetition, so what would be the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: This is it. Perhaps you have to many arguments to the initializer, which is why it seems odd.

Comment: Rafe is right. If you're passing in that many variables, why not just pass in a dict itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can avoid doing that with something like:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, etc):
        self.__dict__.update(locals())
```

then all these arguments become members (including the self argument). So you may remove it with: `self.__dict__.pop('self')`

I don't know how pythonic this approach is, but it works.

PS:
If you're wondering what `__dict__` is, it's a dict that holds every member of an instance in the form `{'member1': value, 'member2': value}`

`locals()` is a function that returns a dict with local variables.

Comment: No. When you declare `__slots__`, Python removes the `__dict__` element. BTW, you should only use `__slots__` when you have too many instances of a Class and you're concerned about memory usage.

Comment: @JBernardo - the reason I bring it up is because this is limited in applicability, and might fail for reasons not obvious to the OP. The point of slots is **not** to save memory.

Comment: Fiddling with `__dict__` also bypasses descriptors (e.g. properties). The bottom line is, you shouldn't fiddle with it at all. Use `for name, val in d.iteritems(): setattr(self, name, val)` if you must.

Comment: @detly Guido himself said on his blog "History of Python" that the main reason for __slots__ is performance. http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html

Comment: @JBernardo - Sure... but to be pedantic, saving memory and performance are not the same thing. Anyway, @delnan made my point better.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do:

```
self.__dict__.update(locals())
```

Comment: things like this are what give python a bad name.