# What's wrong with using python locals() to set class attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes

For my current project, I've defined a number of classes, each of which is initialized with a number of inputs. Much like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025758/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-set-class-variables), I would like to set each input to a class attribute, but I would like to avoid setting each attribute separately. I realize there several ways to do this; my preferred way is the following:

```
class foo(object):
  def __init__(self,a=1,b=2,c=2):
    inpt = locals()
    for k,v in inpt.items():
      if not k in ('self',):
        setattr(self,k,v)
```

My question is: What are the pitfalls of using locals() this way? This seems to work well, but I've picked up some unease from programmers I work with, as well as from some of the comments on other threads (do this "if you must"). However, no one has been able to tell me explicitly what can go wrong, or say precisely what makes them uneasy. So... what's wrong with it?

Comment: `locals()` is contingent on the scope in which the call is made, producing different effects.

Comment: No, `if k != 'self'` ;-)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: no, thats the wrong test. Perhaps `if k != 'self'` but presumably there could be more strings to test against.

Comment: _"what's wrong with it ?"_ So, in brief, it is rather confusing ... to me at least ;)

Comment: Maintainability is an issue. If someone adds code before `inpt = locals()` at some future date (lets say they decide that `c` needs some processing before being added to the instance), the result is unwanted and incorrect values on the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Zen of Python #2 : "Explicit is better than implicit."

Zen of Python #3 : "Simple is better than complex."

Zen of Python #7 : "Readability counts."

In your code sample, you'd get the same result with exactly as many lines of code using the explicit way, *and* it would be much more easy to understand and maintain.

So: there's nothing technically wrong with your code snippet, but you're trading three important Python values (explicit, simple and readable) for... well, for what exactly ? A couple lines of code for the most complex cases ?

Now there are contexts where such a solution might make sense (ORM "model" base class comes to mind), but then you'd probably use `**kwargs` instead of named args and `locals()`.

Comment: What you're trading those three important principles for is DRY. That is to say, the questioner wants to write a "vanilla" `__init__` method that turns a specified list of constructor parameters into instance attributes, mentioning them only once. The advantages over `**kwargs` are that Python will check the constructor's called correctly, and the caller can use positional args. I agree that in this case DRY isn't worth the candle, but that's "what exactly" :-)